# Blazor Drag and Drop broke between .NET Core 3.0 and .NET 6.0

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side, .net-6.0

I followed [Chris Saintys demo](https://chrissainty.com/investigating-drag-and-drop-with-blazor/) for drag and drop which was very clever. The source can be downloaded from his [git.](https://github.com/chrissainty/SimpleDragAndDropWithBlazor) I added the [polyfill](https://github.com/Bernardo-Castilho/dragdroptouch) to make the example work on mobile.

```
<script id="DragDropTouch" src="https://bernardo-castilho.github.io/DragDropTouch/DragDropTouch.js"></script>
```

I use [Conveyor](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vs-publisher-1448185.ConveyorbyKeyoti) to debug drag and drop on mobile and everything works great (Safari and Chrome on IOS mobile ). Unfortunately if I upgrade the demo to .NET 6.0 from .NET Core 3.0 the `@ondragstart` and `@ondrop` no longer fire on the mobile. It's odd that even though on mobile the events are ignored on blazor, they are still raised by javascript. Therefore the polyfill is still working.

**For example on mobile while the following javascript *dragstart* is firing;**

```
document.addEventListener('dragstart', function(ev) {
    if (ev.target.classList.contains('draggable')) {
        console.log('dragging');
    } else {
        console.log('ignoring draggable');
    }
});
```

**The following blaor *dragstart* is being ignored;**

```
<li class="draggable" draggable="true" title="@JobModel.Description" @ondragstart="@(() => HandleDragStart(JobModel))" >
    <p class="description">@JobModel.Description</p>
    <p class="last-updated"><small>Last Updated</small> @JobModel.LastUpdated.ToString("HH:mm.ss tt")</p>
</li>

@code {
    [CascadingParameter] JobsContainer Container { get; set; }
    [Parameter] public JobModel JobModel { get; set; }

    private void HandleDragStart(JobModel selectedJob)
    {
        Container.Payload = selectedJob;
    }
}
```

What could be causing this behavior by upgrading .NET versions?

**Note** that everything works perfectly fine on desktop versions in both .NET 6.0 and .NET Core 3.0.

EDIT: I've added some [repositories to demonstrate this issue.](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/42517#issuecomment-1173999381)

Comment: If you have a way to reliably reproduce this, you should report to Microsoft via GitHub for example, https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues

Comment: @LexLi I took your recommendation and opened an issue here: https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/42517

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was the polyfill. Fix for .NET 6.0 can be found here: [#41394 (comment)](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/41394#issuecomment-1113146280)

Answer (score 0):

The solution is here :

- In index.html, add this lines :
  "script id="DragDropTouch" src="js/DragDropTouch.js"></script"
- Add your own "DragDropTouch.js" in your js folder
- In this file "DragDropTouch.js" : add in line 59 (in var DataTransfer = (function () {... block ) :
  Object.defineProperty(DataTransfer.prototype, "files", {
  /**
  * Added as fix for .NET6 Blazor Server
  */
  get: function () {
  return {};
  },
  enumerable: true,
  configurable: true
  });
  Object.defineProperty(DataTransfer.prototype, "items", {
  /**
  * Added as fix for .NET6 Blazor Server
  */
  get: function () {
  return {};
  },
  enumerable: true,
  configurable: true
  });

See the solution :
https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/41394#issuecomment-1113146280

Comment: Hello, this is the code the link in my answer points to.